# multiple selected html table row data using checkbox is not sending to a email address

Tags: php

I have a html table fetching data from database. i want to select some of the row data using checkbox. i have set the unique value token no to the checkbox and i want to send the checked data to a email address. The issue is only the one row data is sending to the mail, multiple row data is not sending

```
<form method="post" name="myForm">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 2%;">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="email" class="col-lg-9 form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required="">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="col-lg-2 btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="margin-left: 10px;"></i> Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Subproduct</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    /*select query here*/
    while($val = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval))        
    {?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name="checkbox[]" id="chk" value="<?php echo $val['tno']?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['product'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['subproduct'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val['name'];?></td>

   </tr>
   <?php           
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the php code is below

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //$count=1;
    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
        $chk_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "select * from newstock WHERE tno='$chk_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $val=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $product=$val['product'];
        $subproduct=$val['subproduct'];
        $name=$val['name'];
        $quantity=$val['pcs'];
        $gwt=$val['gwt'];
        $nwt=$val['nwt'];
        $tno=$val['tno'];
        $bookno=$val['bookno'];
        $dealer=$val['dealer'];
        $co='<tr>';
        $co.= '<td>Product:'. $product. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Subproduct: '. $subproduct . '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Name: '. $name. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Pcs: '. $quantity. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Gross Weight: '. $gwt . '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Net Weight: '. $nwt. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Token No: '. $tno. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Book No: '. $bookno. '</td>';
        $co.= '<td>Dealer: '. $dealer . '</td>';
        $co.= '</tr>';
    }
    $mailto = $email;
    $mailSub = "Product Details";
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail ->IsSmtp();
    $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail ->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail ->IsHTML(true);
    $mail ->Username = "kothariorg.group@gmail.com";
    $mail ->Password = "kotharigroup@123";
    $mail ->SetFrom("noreply@kothari.com");
    $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
    $mail ->Body = $co;
    $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
    else
    {
        header('location: dashboard.php');
    }
}?>
```

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: i am not getting any error. if i select more than one row data and send it . only last selected row value is getting in mail. i want each selected row data should come

Comment: Ah, ok, I miss understood your question, to me it reads as if no email is sent at all in that situation.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Please learn about the benefits of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "paramter binding" to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual issue is this line:

```
$co='<tr>';
```

Here you reset `$co` in each iteration of your loop, so you basically drop everything you have gathered so far.

Instead you should consider placing the data you created in each iteration in an array and imploding that once you have finished looping. So something like that:

```
[...]
$coBuffer = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
    [...]
    $co='<tr>';
    $co.= '<td>Product:'. $product. '</td>';
    [...]
    $co.= '</tr>';
    $coBuffer[] = $co;
}
$coBody = implode("\n", $coBuffer);
```

Now you have collected all the "rows" of your data on the final `$coBody` which you can use to assemble your email message body.

Answer (score 1):

Check for loop. after every iteration

```
$co
```

$co variable get new value.

Here is the fix :

```
$co = '';

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
    $chk_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "select * from newstock WHERE tno='$chk_id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $val=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $product=$val['product'];
    $subproduct=$val['subproduct'];
    $name=$val['name'];
    $quantity=$val['pcs'];
    $gwt=$val['gwt'];
    $nwt=$val['nwt'];
    $tno=$val['tno'];
    $bookno=$val['bookno'];
    $dealer=$val['dealer'];
    $co .='<tr>';
    $co.= '<td>Product:'. $product. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Subproduct: '. $subproduct . '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Name: '. $name. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Pcs: '. $quantity. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Gross Weight: '. $gwt . '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Net Weight: '. $nwt. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Token No: '. $tno. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Book No: '. $bookno. '</td>';
    $co.= '<td>Dealer: '. $dealer . '</td>';
    $co.= '</tr>';
}
```

Try to replace this code.